# JSON not getting created Properly

Tags: java, json

This is my whole program

```
public class Test {


}
```

Comment: name still inside `T3`.

Comment: Keys in objects are not ordinal.  Functionally there should be no difference between `name` being first or second in the property list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it the way you want it to be. Only thing is the order of the objects inside T3 are different, which doesn't really matter.

You say **After T3 the name is coming out of it.**
But it is actually inside T3.

EDIT: Change your processMap to this:

```
 JSONArray array =new JSONArray(); 
 for (String key : map.keySet()) { 
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); 
      json.put("name", key);      
      json.put("T" + level, processList(map.get(key), level + 1)); 
      array.put(json); 
 } 
 return array;
```

Comment: Thank you very much , could you please tell me why its not printing the first key Popcorn ?? where its being overridden ??

Comment: It's being overriden in processMap. You are using the same JSONObject for both of them, and it is overriding the first one. I suggest return an array of JSONObjects, and print them in a loop. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I have done exactly the same what you mentioned , but still its being overriden . please see the updated Question with the latest code.

Answer (score 0):

look this block ..

```
 "T3": [
            {
                "T4": [
                    {
                        "name": "Strawbeerry",
                        "leaf": []
                    }
                ],
                "name": "KoolCool"
            }
        ]
```

Whatever it is  name && T4 presently inside in `json block {}`

```
     T3[0].T4
     T3[0].name
```

both of present in array[0].so,no need for reformatting.